# Laptop goes to sleep before asking for password (using cryptsetup)

Tags: 16.04, boot, laptop, cryptsetup

This is my very first post so I will try to be as precise as possible.

I have a Razer Blade Stealth 2017 with Ubuntu 16.04 using full disk encryption. It was going great, being able to type my password both on boot and at login, until it blew away some weeks ago.

The problem is, only one out of 5/6 attempts to boot my laptop result in it asking for my cryptsetup password, the others resulting in it going to sleep for no apparent reason. To quit this state I am forced to "hard shutdown" it & try again.

Do you have some hints or solutions? It would make my life so easier!

Thanks in advance!